# SQL SELECT and timestamp columns

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

In my application i have a java `Timestamp dateCreated`, which is inserted to a mysql Timestamp colum. Inserting is no problem, i use a prepared statement and `statement.setTimestamp(dateCreated)`.

Now i need to select a row with the dateCreated as unique identifier. my method gets another java Timestamp object.how does the SQL query work in this case? i havent figured out how to compare the java timestamp to the mysql one.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_column = ???`

Thanks!

Comment: Post the Java code that you are using to execute this query.

Comment: `private final static String SELECT_SPEL = "SELECT * FROM spel WHERE datumAangemaakt LIKE %d";`

and further:

String.format(SELECT_SPEL, timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you will use a similar setTimestamp method as you did with the insert.

```
   Timestamp t = ???;


   String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_column = ?";
   preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   preparedStatement.setTimestamp(t);
```

etc.

Comment: i was unaware prepared statements also work on select queries. thanks!